# How to update an expression tree with GraphDiff

Tags: c#, entity-framework, graphdiff

The object graph I'm working with is basically:

```
public class Resource
    {
        public string Forename { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public int EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Skill> Skills { get; set; }
    }
public class Skill
    {
        public int SkillId{get; private set;}
        public Technology Technology { get; set; }
        public SkillCategory Category { get; set; }
        public SkillCompetency Competency { get; set; }    

    }
```

A new skill can be added to the user by selecting combinations of existing Technology, SkillCategory, SkillCompetency. I've been trying (and failing!) to use GraphDiff to prevent EF from trying to add duplicate Technology, SkillCategory, SkillCompetency records.
This seems like it should be simple to achieve using GraphDiff but being a relative newby to EF couple with only just finding GraphDiff I'm struggling.

Any ideas?

Comment: Also, if GraphDiff is behaving unexpectedly please do not use the NuGet package but build from source as the package is currently quite outdated. I expect it to be updated soon, though..

Comment: Thanks Andy, I'm just trying out your answer. GraphDiff appears to do exactly whaty we want so it would be great if we can actually use it :-)

Comment: The NuGet package for GraphDiff has been updated yesterday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GraphDiff basically distinguishes two kinds of relations: *owned* and *associated*. *Owned* can be interpreted as "being a part of" meaning that anything that is owned will be inserted/updated/deleted with its owner. The other kind of relation handled by GraphDiff is *associated* which means that only relations to, but not the associated entities themselves are changed by GraphDiff when updating a graph.

Coming back to your scenario: you don't want duplicate `Technology`, `Category` or `Competency` entities, but `Skills` are just combinations of those, so duplicate `Skills` are fine. To model this using GraphDiff, you tell it to consider `Skills` as parts of a `Resource` (*owned* by a `Resource`) and `Technology`, `Category` and `Competency` as *associations* of a `Skill`. This is mapped like so:

```
// these three entities are all managed separately and have already been saved elsewhere
Technology entityFrameworkCodeFirst;
Category objectRelationalMappers;
Competency notThatIncompetent;

using (DbContext context = new WhatEverYourContextIsNamed())
{
    Resource developer = new Resource
    {
        Skills = new List<Skill> 
        {  
            new Skill
            {
                Technology = entityFrameworkCodeFirst,
                Category = objectRelationalMappers,
                Competency = notThatIncompetent,
            }
        } 
    };
    context.UpdateGraph(developer, 
        map => map.OwnedCollection(r => r.Skills, 
            with => with.AssociatedEntity(skill => skill.Technology)
                        .AssociatedEntity(skill => skill.Category)
                        .AssociatedEntity(skill => skill.Competency)));
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Ok, I've tried your suggestion. I think you might have misunderstood my problem.
The problem I'm facing is when I add a new skill to a resource the associated objects for Technology, SkillCategory, SkillCompetency competency get added as new items. Since these are reference data as such I don't want them adding.
I think what I'm trying to do is have Technology, SkillCategory, SkillCompetency as AssociatedCollections of Skills which is in turn an AssociatedCollection of Resource but I can't seem to configure it.

Comment: You're correct, I misunderstood your question yesterday - I've updated my answer, hopefully I didn't misunderstand you again.. :)

Comment: Thanks Andy.
The above code is where I actually got to myself following your initial reply. However it didn't work - I got a replication of developer!
My scenario was:
1) Create a developer, add a skill and then update/save the entities
2) With the same developer add a second skill, then update and save
This gave me a second developer record.
My problem was after the first update/save the developer id was not being updated with the db identity value.

Comment: The code I was executing was: context.UpdateGraph(developer,.....)
I  assumed since developer was a reference type it's id would be just updated. 
Once I changed the code to: developer = context.UpdateGraph(developer,....)
It all worked lovely. Also I think the rebuild also helped.
Thanks very much for your help.